# Why am I managing to set the size of divs in percent?

Tags: html, css

Guys I'm already getting slightly annoyed, I'm not able to find out why I'm managing to set the height of the divs in percentage, because I saw it on a website just to confirm that setting the height of the divs in percentage does not work, **unless it is div  be a child div,** so why the hell can I set the height of the elements in percent even when the div doesn't have a parent div?
**Well, my body code in css looks like this:**

```
html,body{                                      
 width:100%;                                     
 height:100%;                                    
 font-family:Verdana;
 color:#fff;                                     
 backgroundd:#151515;                             
}
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening?  Why I’m very curious to know why percentage height works when it shouldn’t, **this shouldn’t happen right?**

Comment: a parent doesn't need to be a `div`. It can be any kind of element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent element... `body` has a width and height of 100% (being the browser frame, should the `html` element have a width and height of 100%), then of course any children of the `body` element is going to be relative to that.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">test</div>
</body>
```

This is exactly what should be happening.

Comment: You are right, I had thought about this possibility but I thought I had excluded the `height: 100%;` and tested this hypothesis in one of my attempts to solve this, but I think I didn’t get to do it;